# R- keep a fixed number of observation per ID

Tags: r, subset

I have  a large data frame like the following one

[image]

I want to keep equal observations per ID (only 3 in this case) 
also I want to keep enough intervals between observation (ie: to keep first and last one, and another on between them)
how can I subset my data and keep the required only

so the final be like this

[image]

Comment: image urls are broken

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide some data to work with. What code have you tried? Are there any rules to picking the "middle" id/observation?

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(ID) %>% sample_n(3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[c(1,.N/2, .N)],  by = ID]
```

Comment: There is a comma missing: setDT(df1)[, .SD[c(1,.N/2, .N)], by = ID]